# How to use JCheckBox to number/name check boxes in a collection i.e. key1, key2, etc

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

In a servlet I have this

while (result.next()) {
  JCheckBox key = new JCheckBox();   *new statement I'm thinking to add in

key.setSelected(false);            *new statement I'm thinking to add in

resultsArray[rowcount][0] = result.getString(1); This is the actual value of key

resultsArray[rowcount][1] = result.getString(2);

.
.
.

end

do  ...

search_results.add(resultsArray[row][col])

end

helps to fill up the string array   and...

session.setAttribute("searchresults",search_results);

So that I can process it in the jsp

I populate resultsArray with the results of a query.
results.getString(1) will always have the key value of the record in the table of the database searched.

I list the results of my search from the jsp with

td  align=left valign=top>

input type="checkbox" name="key" value=<%=resultsArray.get(pos + 0)%>/>

/td>

The page lists the results you searched for (with a checkbox) and you now check off the records you really want to delete. I will then come back with that smaller list of information and ask you to "check off one more time if you are sure you want to delete these records".

The problem is I while name="key<%=i%> might very well display key1, key2, key3, etc in the jsp. In the servlet I am not sure how to make

JCheckBox keyN = new JCheckBox();

happen.  Any and all suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Nelson

Comment: Integer i = 1;
String key = "key";
 while (result.next()) {
   key = "key" + i.toString();
   resultsArray[rowcount][0] = key; 
   resultsArray[rowcount][1] = result.getString(1);

Comment: Added code to number each checkbox Still unclear how to use JCheckBox to test box selected, or should just go with onclick() js event.
Integer i = 1;
String key = "key";
 while (result.next()) {
   key = "key" + i.toString();
   resultsArray[rowcount][0] = key; 
   resultsArray[rowcount][1] = result.getString(1);
   .
   . 
while (rowsremaining > 0) { 
      Keyname = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 0) + "";
      Keyvalue = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 1) + "";   
      .
      . 
       <td  align=left valign=top>
       <input type="checkbox" name=<%=Keyname%> value=<%=Keyvalue%> />
      </td>

Answer (score 0):

I was being overly complicated. All that I had to do was to process the posted argument. to be able to redisplay the choices that were selected on the previous page. I didn't need JCheckBox at all for any of this.

```
       String onoff = request.getParameter(Keyvalue);
```

%>

```
       <% if ((onoff == null) || (onoff.equals(""))) { %>
          <input type="checkbox" name=<%=Keyvalue%> />
       <% } else { 
            if (onoff.equals("off")) { %> 
               <input type="checkbox" name=<%=Keyvalue%> />
       <% } else { %>
               <input type="checkbox" name=<%=Keyvalue%> checked /> 
       <% }} %>
```